# Feather edge corners in a table how?

Tags: css, css-tables

I used to use this kind of "documenting**" format, just an example:

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"><base target="_blank"></head><body> 
<table class="tablet"><tr><td><pre style="margin-bottom:0;"> 
find . -type f -size 0
</pre></td></tr></table> 
</body></html>
```

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lTG5.png

** to e.g. document Linux/etc. howtos.

style.css

```
table.tablet
    {
        width: 98%;
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #000000;
        padding-top: 5;
        padding-bottom: 5;
        padding-right: 10;
        padding-left: 10;
        font-size: 110%;
        font-family: "times";
        font-weight: normal;
        border-left: 5px solid #000000;
        margin-left:10px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

body
    {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        color: #000000;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        font-size: 80%;
        font-family: "times";
        background-repeat:repeat;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Q: I need to make "feather edges" from these "sharp corners". How?

Example for the "feather/rounded edges":

http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=175880
Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRm3t.png

Answer (score 1):

Use a `div` instead of a `table`, then use CSS3's [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/border-radius) property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #ffffff;
                color: #000000;
                padding:0;
                font-size: 80%;
                font-family: "Times";
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            div.tablet{
                width: 98%;
                height:20px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                padding: 5px 10px;
                font-size: 110%;
                border-left: 5px solid #000000;
                margin-left:10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                border-radius: 6px;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="tablet">find . -type f -size 0</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/VQTAK/)

Note that `border-radius` is only supported in IE9, Safari 5.0, Firefox 4.0, and Chrome 4.0 or higher. Older browsers will see a square box instead of the rounded one. If that's a problem for you, you need to create your rounded corners with a background image. If the box will have a variable width, you'll need to create two rounded background images (one for the left and one for the right) then apply them with CSS using the [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) technique.

Comment: wow, this one works under firefox-3.6.17-1.fc14.i686 but it doesn't work under: google-chrome-stable-12.0.742.91-87961.i386

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 12.0.742.91 for me. [ [Screenshot.](https://img.skitch.com/20110614-t95cnqw7b8fbdjciy4xpyb3n5r.jpg) ]